# CVar optimization in python

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

I am new in python. I am trying to write a code on portfolio optimization. More specifically, I want to apply the following, using scipy.optimize

[CvAR definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO71P.png)

```
def minimize_cvar(sim_corr_rets, er, target_return, alpha=0.01):
    """
    Returns the optimal weights (n x 1) that achieve the target return
    and minimize cvar, based on a set of simulated correlated returns (n x S)
    and an array of expected returns (er)=(n x 1)
    """
    n = er.shape[0] # number of assets
    S = sim_corr_rets.shape[1] # number of simulations
    
    init_guess = np.repeat(1/n, n)
    
    bounds = ((0.0, 1.0),) * n # an n-tuple of 2-tuples!
    
    def cvar(var, var_dev, S, alpha):
        return var+np.sum(var_dev)/(S*(1-alpha))   

    constraints_1 = {'type': 'eq','fun': lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1},
    constraints_2 = {'type': 'eq','args': (er,),'fun': lambda weights, er: target_return - weights.T @ er}
      
    cons_3 = []
    for i in range(S): cons_3.append({'type':'ineq','args': (sim_corr_rets,), 'fun': lambda weights, var, var_dev, i = i: var_dev.iloc[i] - weights.T @ sim_corr_rets.iloc[:,i] + var})    
    constraints_3 = tuple(cons_3)
    
    cons_4 = []
    for i in range(S): cons_4.append({'type':'ineq','fun': lambda var_dev, i = i: var_dev.iloc[i]})    
    constraints_4 = tuple(cons_4)
  
    results = minimize(cvar, 
                       init_guess,
                       method='SLSQP',
                       options={'disp': False},
                       constraints=(constraints_1, constraints_2, constraints_3, constraints_4),
                       bounds=bounds)
    return results.x
```

When I ran this code, I got the following error (related to the constraints most probably) :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5816\2309333620.py in <module>
      3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      4 import optimizer as opt
----> 5 opt.minimize_cvar(sim_corr_rets, ERA, target_return=0.03, alpha=0.01)

~\optimizer.py in minimize_cvar(sim_corr_rets, er, target_return, alpha)
    201     constraints_4 = tuple(cons_4)
    202 
--> 203     results = minimize(cvar, 
    204                        init_guess,
    205                        method='SLSQP',

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    655             fd_needed = (not callable(jac))
    656             for con in constraints:
--> 657                 if not callable(con.get('jac', None)):
    658                     fd_needed = True
    659 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can anyone help me on how I should structure this problem to get the weights that minimize the portfolio CVaR? Moreover, I am not sure if var_dev is a variable or not.

Thanks.

Comment: The error suggest that you are trying to treat a tuple as a dictionary. What line is giving the error? Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks. I have included the full traceback above.

Comment: It looks like the function is expecting an iterable of dictionaries but you are passing an iterable of tuples. Look at the documentation carefully to see how to invoke the minimization function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried various changes but I couldn't go any further. Could you please provide me with a more specific hint or advice on which element of the code creates this error? This would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CVaR optimization in practice is usually solved via linear programming, see  https://doi.org/10.21314/JOR.2000.038.

So a good first step is to use scipy's linprog: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Instead of minimize with 'SLSQP'.

There are also already good CVaR optimization implementations in Python. If you browse GitHub, you should be able to draw inspiration from these.